# Include more than 3 parameters in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

What is the best way to use ggplot to make a grouped bar chart of my data below?

Finding it difficult to get all the parameters in into ggplot. I would like to have "bathng" and P_Hygn on the x axis while EnteredARC would be the fill.y axis will be in proportion values. The values of Bathing and P_hygn is from 0 to 5, where: 0 = independent, 1 = supervision, 2 = moderate, 3 = minimal and 4 is severe and 5 is coma.

```
     gender EnteredARC  Ethnicity Bathng P_Hygn
1:      M   Entry_RC    European      4      2
2:      F   NoEntry_RC  European      3      0
3:      F   NoEntry_RC  European      0      0
4:      M   Entry_RC    European      3      4
5:      F   Entry_RC    European      5      2
6:      F   NoEntry_RC  European      2      0
7:      F   Entry_RC    European      3      1
8:      M   Entry_RC    European      4      2
9:      M   Entry_RC    European      8      2



gender EnteredARC Ethnicity Bathng P_Hygn
1:      M   Entry_RC  European      4      2
2:      F NoEntry_RC  European      3      0
3:      F NoEntry_RC  European      0      0
4:      M   Entry_RC  European      3      4
5:      F   Entry_RC  European      5      2
6:      F NoEntry_RC  European      2      0
7:      F   Entry_RC  European      3      1
8:      M   Entry_RC  European      4      2
9:      M   Entry_RC  European      8      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(gender=c('M','F','F','M','F','F','F','M','M'), 
                 EnteredARC=c('Entry_RC','NoEntry_RC','NoEntry_RC','Entry_RC','Entry_RC','NoEntry_RC','Entry_RC','Entry_RC','Entry_RC'), 
                 Ethnicity=c('European','European','European','European','European','European','European','European','European'), 
                 Bathng=c(4,3,0,3,5,2,3,4,8), 
                 P_Hygn=c(2,0,0,4,2,0,1,2,2))
g <- ggplot(df,aes(factor(Bathng),color=gender,size=P_Hygn)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=EnteredARC)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("dark grey", "light grey"))
ggplotly(g)
```

Comment: Please don't forget to let us know if this is the solution you were expecting as it'll surely help others in case they face similar issue.